# How to make Up down left right movement in one function or method?

Tags: java, android

how do i make this code go as one line? or call up down left right in a dynamic function.

```
    public  class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float  x =moveOBJECT.getX(),y=moveOBJECT.getY(),h=moveOBJECT.getHeight(),w=moveOBJECT.getWidth(),ih=img.getHeight(),iw=img.getWidth(),val=15;
        movement(v,x,y,h,w,ih,iw,val);
        return true;
    }
    public void movement(View v,float x,float y, float h, float w, float ih, float iw,float val){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonUP){
            moveOBJECT.setY((y >= 0) ?y - val : y);
        }else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonDOWN){
            moveOBJECT.setY((y + h< ih) ? y + val : y);
        }else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonLEFT){
            moveOBJECT.setX((x >= 0) ? x - val : x);
        }else{
            moveOBJECT.setX((x + w < iw) ? x + val : x);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: btw, moveOBJECT is a textview. i'm trying to move it in 4 directions using 4 buttons. but someone told me that i could do it in one line or a dynamic function.

Comment: Why would you want it as a one-line function?

Comment: @abbath for educational purposes. to learn. someone told me it can be done in one line. just out of curiosity, and as I said to learn.

Answer (score 0):

How about a single well defined class?

[VelocityTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) does what you generally want.

Just have it add the movements with .addMovement(event) then query you can determine the direction by the magnitude and sign of the getXVelocity() and getYVelocity() functions.

That or track the touches yourself, as you'd end up needing to do something like that anyway which violates the constraits of your question. But, you should be able to just feed the touches into that and easily determine

```
return (Math.abs(tracker.getXVelocity()) > Math.abs(tracker.getYVelocity())?
((tracker.getXVelocity() > 0)?LEFT:RIGHT)
:((tracker.getYVelocity() > 0)?UP:DOWN)
```

Or whatever weird "I want it to be a single line" nonsense you come up with.